# How can I allocate a piece of memory from a certain physical memory in embedded arm processor?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, zynq

I am using zynq device, trying to transfer data from DRAM to the peripheral of ARM by a piece of standalone program (without OS). In the example code, I found this code to statement the source address and destination address of the transaction.

```
volatile static u8 SrcBuffer[BUFFER_BYTESIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));
volatile static u8 DestBuffer[BUFFER_BYTESIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));
```

Since there's no OS, what's the value of address from? How can I change it?

Comment: If you want a specific area of RAM to be used for something special, I suggest you set up the linker script to reserve the area so it's not used for anything else. Then simply use a pointer to the start of the memory.

Comment: Maybe the example used DMA?

Comment: Yes, it use the DMA. The srcBuffer and DestBuffer is for DMA transaction

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. "what's the value of address from?" What address? Those are two DMA buffers. They will have memory addresses like everything else, but I don't see how knowing that will be relevant for your program.

Comment: `SrcBuffer` and `DestBuffer` will be allocated with other 'C' data.  The `volatile` tells the compiler to handle the data with care; this is probably not a good way to do this.  Google *memory barrier* for more on that topic.  The only thing special about the buffer is it is 64 byte aligned, which is probably a requirement of the hardware.  If you are porting to Linux/BSD, they have an MMU enabled and the bare metal may not.  MMU also implies cache and the *original code* may have issue if it was written with an assumption the cache is off.  See: [ask].

Comment: @artlessnoise This is most likely not a multi-core system. And I don't believe neither data nor instruction cache can be used for DMA buffers, since the CPU isn't even involved?

Comment: @Lundin  `SrcBuffer` is declared as a variable, so a CPU can use it.  What use is DMA if nothing ever use it?  Certainly something needs to populate the source buffer as it looks like memory to memory.  Also, it doens't need to be multi-core; the DMA engine is active in the use of the memory.  If the buffer is cached and the CPU originally populates it, it might not be flushed to the physical memory the DMA peripheral uses.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a section a in the linker file and then place the data in it using (for GCC):

`__attribute__ (( section ( "your_section" ) ) )`

In the linker file (will have other stuff in it already as well) something like:

```
MEMORY
{
   ....will be other stuff here
   ....
   YOUR_MEMORY_NAME : ORIGIN = 0xWhatever, Length = a_length // Creates a memory region 
}

SECTIONS
{
   ...
   ...

   .something_data :
   {
      *(your_data)
   } > YOUR_MEMORY_NAME 

   ...

}
```

Comment: Some nits.  I think "your_data" and "your_section" need to be the same word?  Also, it is probably good to 64 byte align `.something_data` as someone could potentially add other sections to `YOUR_MEMORY_NAME`.  I agree that the linker is a better tool to do these things, but I don't see how anything was solved for the OP?  Maybe he wants a compile time address for the memory?

Comment: You are correct "your_data" and "your_section" should be the same word. Alignment is also probably wise.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the piece of information provided it seems that the code is doing DMA to and from DRAM to a particular hardware buffer register of the peripheral of the micro-controller.

There should be a code where the hardware peripheral register address is used like SBUF or I2C_DATA_REG or something similar to this.
If you want to know the address of both the buffers you may need Debugger using which you can view the address of both the arrays or if you have UART working then you can print it on console.
If you want to fix the memory of both the buffers then you need to follow what @Realtime Rik suggested